# Sign in to Google in Chrome without signing in on Android

Tags: chrome-for-android

On desktop, you can sign in to multiple google accounts by clicking on your picture and selecting "add account".

You used to be able to do this on Android. Chrome would automatically sign you in if you were signed in to a google account in Android, but you could sign in to as many google accounts as you wanted.

That feature seems to be broken/gone now.

Now I can only "manage device accounts" which takes me to the Android screen for adding a Google account to Android.  I don't want to add a Google account to Android, I just want to sign in to some Google accounts in Chrome. I don't want the Google account device policies or mixing their contacts with mine or accidentally being in the wrong Google Play account when downloading an app or any of that.

Is there a way to force Chrome to let me sign in to multiple Google accounts without adding the account to Android itself?

I've tested this on a factory-reset Pixel 1 with all the updates and a Pixel 4.

Comment: Perhaps using another browser will also help you to achieve this.

Comment: Firefox on Android supports logging in to multiple google accounts but there are several drawbacks to this which prevent me from using it as my default browser.